# Start an Android animation synchronized with another

Tags: android, android-animation

I run a pulse animation (= scale down and scale up) on a view with a no-limit repeat mode :

```
view1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pulse));
```

Then, with an event based on a button, I start another pulse animation in another view.

```
view2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pulse));
```

Is it possible for the second to wait for the first, so they can be synchronized? (scale up in the same time and scale down in the same time).

Comment: You should be able to synchronize `Animation`s using [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)s.

Comment: Ah good idea : in the onAnimationRepeat of view1 I can put the startAnimation instruction of view2 when a flag is activated by the button. It may work.